Weird results of 2*3 of Fisher's exact test in SPSS
I have two categorical variables: age group (4 years old, 8 years old) and intervention (low, medium, high). I want to examine the differences in intervention between the two age groups, because the expected value is less than 5 cells. I performed Fisher's test with passed z-test (Bonferroni correction) in SPSS 27.
1、The results seem peculiar. From the chart, we can see that in the 4-year-old group, there are 11 children who chose "Low" and 15 who chose "Medium" with the subscripts for these cells being "a" and "b" respectively. This suggests that 4-year-old children tend to prefer "Medium" over "Low”. However, what puzzles me is that there are only 4 children who chose "High" and 15 who chose "Medium” yet these two cells share the same subscript "b", implying that there is no significant difference in the choices of 4-year-old children between these two intervention methods. Why is that? From a proportion perspective, the difference in the number of children choosing "Medium" versus "High" is clearly more pronounced.
2、I conducted a multinomial logistic regression analysis on my data in R, and the results indicated that among 4-year-olds, more children chose "Medium" over "High". However, there was no difference between "Low" and "Medium" as well as "Low" and "High". The inconsistency in the results obtained from these two methods is quite perplexing. Why?
I have consulted relevant materials and found that Fisher's exact test might be more suitable for small samples, while logistic regression is more appropriate for larger samples. Since I only have a sample of 60, I speculate that Fisher's exact test might be more appropriate for my analysis (I am not certain if this is correct).


The reason for some differences being significant and others not, even if the proportions vary more, is sample size. Only 4 children in total chose "high" and that affects the p value.
The choice between logistic regression and chi square (or Fisher's) should not be based on sample size, but on the goals of the analysis and the nature of the relationship. Here, you have a clear relationship. Choice of level might depend on age, but the reverse is nonsensical (age cannot depend on choice).
I would not do multinomial regression here, but ordinal. since "low", "medium", and "high" have a clear order. For discussion of ordinal logistic regression with small samples, see, e.g. this thread.

The fundamental reason is that the Fisher-exact test, the z-test and logistic regression are 3 different tests, and can give different results.
A second reason is that some of your counts are very low (e.g. 0 for 8years/high, or 4 for 2 other cells). With such low counts, the z-test is not appropriate (the normal approximation is unfounded; these binomial distributions do not look normal. Moreover, using a continuous distribution to approximate a discrete one is also unfounded with such low counts). Similalry, logistic regression will not handle the cell with 0 counts.
Note also that SPSS probably used the pooled version of the z-test (assuming equal variances; I am guessing here -not a SPSS expert-, but that version is the most common). The pooled version gives a non-significant result when comparing Medium to High. But if you used the unpooled version (more appropriate in this case because the variance of High is 0...), the result is significant (p=.0244). But not for the Fisher-exact test...
So your best post-hoc test to see where the difference in distribution comes from probably is to stay with Fisher-exact, but this time using a series of 2x2 tables.
Comparing Medium to High with Fisher-exact, there is no significant difference between the 2 age groups, mostly because the counts are so low (so the observed difference could just be due to random sampling). But there would be with an unpooled variance z test...
Now, comparing Low to Medium, there is a significant difference between the age groups.
And comparing Low to High, there also is a significant difference.
And you can even run comparison between, say, Low, and the aggregate of Medium & High, etc.
Alternatively, you could look at simple binomial CI's (because they are also based on the "exact" binomial distribution, just as the Fisher-exact test is), and see which CI's overlap, or do not overlap (you can adjust the $\alpha$ level, to account for multiple comparisons, or not...). And that would reveal the impact of low counts on presence (or absence) of significant results.
